# set the upload_tmp_dir but file no where to be found

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a few image upload scripts and wordpress blog as well.
I think the client tried to upload a 3mb+ images or so and since then everythings stopped working, to further inspection and adding error handlers i found out that

it was UPLOAD TEMP DIR not FOUND

i cant touch the ini file, its shared hosting but i can create a local ini file

i've been told to add php.ini in the public_html folder
it only works i.e prints out the upload_tmp_dir when its in the same folder as the script anyway

i put this in the ini file
upload_tmp_dir = "/home/USER/tmp"
also tried
upload_tmp_dir = "/home/USER/public_html/tmp"

but the first one is where the tmp folder was but i tried creating it else where with 777 permissions

leave ini in same folder as the script and calling
echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');

gives me: [given i set it to that]
/home/USER/tmp

sys_get_temp_dir();

gave me
/tmp

anyway NOW i get no errors, says file is uploaded but its no where to be found.
not sure WTF is going on but clients wrecking my head and so is this.

Comment: did you use move_uploaded_file function?

Comment: Where are you running the script from? You don't need to specify the full route, just the relative route to the place you're executing from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will delete uploaded files when the script exits, unless you've moved/copied the file somewhere else yourself. The upload process isn't a "do it now and come back later to deal with it" system. It's "deal with it now, or it's gone".

To retrieve the file's temporary storage location/name, you use [`$_FILES['namegiveninform']['tmp_name']`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), and generally would use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) to move the file into its permanent storage location.