# php upload file with custom upload_tmp_dir

Tags: php, file-upload

I would like to upload files to my server using php and xmlhttprequest in POST.

But my /tmp dir is too small, so I created a new tmp folder for upload with 777 access, and I changed the vhost conf file to set upload_tmp_dir to this folder's path.

If i display phpinfo, this folder appears as the upload_tmp_dir.

But when I upload a file, nothing appears in the new tmp folder but I can see this type of file in /tmp : 20140321-165951-Uyxh938AAQEAACcDEeEAAAAC-request_body-uW4YRM

What can I do to get php upload to use the tmp folder I created ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Maybe too obvious, but did you restart Apache after the change?

Comment: I was going to mention that earlier also @BarryDevSF

Comment: [`See this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16091596/) which may help.

Comment: [`This Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3105943/) may also explain it. I quote from the answer given: *"PHP will delete uploaded files when the script exits, unless you've moved/copied the file somewhere else yourself. The upload process isn't a "do it now and come back later to deal with it" system. It's "deal with it now, or it's gone"."*

Comment: Yes I restarted the apache server.
And in my php page I use move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$sNewPath);

Comment: dont forget that the new dir should have the 755 permission, and the own/group be available to the apache / php ... so you could use chown root:www-data /new_upload_dir/ ?

Answer (score 0):

to upload your files into tmp folder, your should use this

```
file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir().'/file.txt', 'content');
```

Comment: My goal is not to upload content in tmp dir.
I'm using an html form to upload file on the server, but the tmp folder is too small on this server, and I'd like to use an other folder as php upload tmp dir, but it does not work.

Comment: maybe your settings wrong or your new **upload_folder** has wrong place
try this :
**upload_tmp_dir = /root/tmp/upload**
**your site location - /root/www/**